# F# how to do List.map in parallel

Tags: parallel-processing, f#

What is the most lightweight, terse way to run the following code in parallel within the standard F# libs? Or failing that any widely used additional libs?

```
let newlist = oldlist |> List.map myComplexFunction
```

The best I could find was

```
let newlist = oldlist |> List.map (fun x -> async { return myComplexFunction x }
                      |> Async.Parallel 
                      |> Async.RunSynchronously
                      |> Array.toList
```

I don't like this because it's 4 lines long and constructs an array that I then have to make back into a list. If I were working with Arrays it would be simple, Array.parallel, but I want to keep that lovely Immutable list functional purity. I just can't believe there is no list alternative, but so far have been unable to find one.
Any good suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `PSeq` module:

```
open Microsoft.FSharp.Collections

let newlist = 
    oldlist 
    |> PSeq.map myComplexFunction
    |> PSeq.toList
```

Comment: The `PSeq` module can now be found in [FSharp.Collections.ParallelSeq](http://fsprojects.github.io/FSharp.Collections.ParallelSeq/).

Answer (score 4):

It's now worth taking a look at [Array.Parallel](https://fsharp.github.io/fsharp-core-docs/reference/fsharp-collections-arraymodule-parallel.html) in F# Core.

```ml
let newlist =
    oldlist
    |> Array.ofList
    |> Array.Parallel.map (fun x -> myComplexFunction x)
    |> Array.toList
```